# Can I assign a c# variable to to the return statement of a javascript function?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Suppose I have a C# variable named currentTab in my razor view.

I have javascript codes that says..

```
<script type="text/javascipt">
    function CurrentTabReturner(){
        var currTab = $("a.current").attr("id");
        return currTab;
    }
</script>
```

Now I want to do this:

```
@currentTab = CurrentTabReturner();
```

Is it possible? Or are there any other ways to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible?

No it is not possible. Server side variables exist on the server. Client side javascript runs inside the client browser much later, where no more any server variables exist. So trying to assign a server side variable to a client side function simply doesn't make sense. On the client you could send normal or asynchronous (AJAX) requests to the server so that server side variables can be updated.